# Gas filled my engine

Tags: fuel-system, gasoline, pump, carburetor

I'm a little puzzled on my 33 I have a 302 ( stroker 363 )) Dart block with brodex heads with a small blower. after blowing up my power glide I pulled the engine and just now reinstalled it. after checking all I turned the key the fuel pump came on but kept running I steped out of the car to hear the bubbling sounds of my carb filling up and filling up my engine. I turned the power off and now will wait for the evap and drain. what could it be ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sounds like you've got a float stuck in the carb. Not sure if your pump is pressure regulated. If it is and the float is stuck, it'll just keep filling the bowl(s) until you turn the key off.

Comment: Is there a fuel return on your carbs?  Have you connected the fuel feed to the fuel return by mistake?

Comment: Yes I do have a return thanks for asking   all fixed as it was the carb, I took it apart 3 times and finally saw the float level was set to high.

Answer (score 1):

Check your carb.  Bad floats.  Bad float adjustment.  Bad needle and seat.
If we are talking Holley 4bbl - look down the throttle bores and see if your see the leak.  That will narrow down if its front or rear fuel bowl.

On other carbs, if the fuel bowl itself leaks, it can drip straight into motor.

Check your fuel pressure - 4psi at idle/no load.  On some race applications where the needle and seat are not large enough, you can boost fuel pressure under WOT to say 6-8psi.

Old motors with mechanical fuel pumps sometimes failed the pump and would fill the engine with gas.

Gas in oil is of course death to the bearings in the motor.